# Change ToolStripDropDownButton Text by Selecting Item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been stuck on this problem for awhile now, and I was hoping for some direction or an answer. How do you change the text of a ToolStripDropDownButton based off of a selected item within itself?

I have a grid that is to be displayed, but I want to change the size of the grid on the fly. By selecting the ToolStripDropDownButton and selecting a predetermined list of grid sizes, the text of the ToolStripDropDownButton should change to show the user the new grid size.

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question, thank you all for the answers.

```
        private void changeGridSizeDropDownButton_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem != null)
        {
            changeGridSizeDropDownButton.Text = e.ClickedItem.Text;
            // This line converts my list gridsize options like 64, 32, and 16
            // and Parses that text into the new selected gridsize.
            gridSize = Int32.Parse(e.ClickedItem.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy you'll see.

```
      myToolStripDropDownButton.DropDownItems[0].Text = "New grid size";
```

The index[0] is the first item in your `DropBox` just change it to access other items.

This is to change the name of the items.

If you need to change Text somewhere on the `ToolStrip` independently from your `DropDownButton` check what item is selected than change

```
       myToolStrip.Items.Add("DefautlGridSize");
       myToolStrip.Items[0].Text("NewGridSize");
```

If you don't need the `ToolStrip` especially I would  consider using a `ComboBox` with a `Label` which would do the job much more simply.

Hope this helped